# Problem does not follow DCP rules when imposing constraints

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I want to find a center point of a dataset with some given inequality constraints using cvxpy.

I have tried to make a constraint such that distance from the optimal point (opt_point) to the origin is greater than a constant, e.g., 300. There are two ways to do this.

First,

```
constraints = [opt_point[0]**2 + opt_point[1]**2 >= 300]
```

This did not work, I realized that it can solve with `<=` inequality but it could not with `>=`. After reading some pages, I realized that the `quad_form` function is convex, so I tried:

```
constraints = [cp.quad_form(opt_point, P)>=300]
```

However, neither can solve the problem.

```py
opt_point = cp.Variable(2);
cost = 0
for i in range(len(xPoints)):
    cost += cp.sum_squares(opt_point-data[i,:])
assert cost.is_convex()
P = cp.diag([1, 1])
constraints =  [cp.quad_form(opt_point, P)>>300]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost),constraints)
prob.solve()
opt_point = opt_point.value;
```

Could you please explain how I can impose more inequality constraints without yielding the following error?

> Problem does not follow DCP rules. However, the problem does follow DGP rules. Consider calling this function with `gp=True`.

Comment: You are trying to create a non-convex constraint, and CVXPY is for convex problems. Think of the feasible region — you take the Euclidean plane, then remove a disk of radius 300. You end up with a plane that has a "hole", which is clearly non-convex.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Even though I tried to close the region as follows:
constraints =  [opt_point[0]**2 + opt_point[1]**2 >= 10 ,opt_point[0]**2 + opt_point[1]**2 <= 100]
The error still appears. How can I resolve this ?. Thanks

Comment: Making the region bounded does not make it convex. You have an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)), which is visibly non-convex.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, Thank you for pointing out my problem. But I am trying to find a way to solve my problem. Can you or anyone suggest me how to transform my problem such that I can get the convexity of the cost function and the constraints?

Comment: That is a mathematical question, not a programming question. I would post a new question at Math SE. No code, just the optimization problem. Some non-convex problems can be solved, just not with CVXPY. Post a link here to the new question.